# ActionMailer method returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have created a simple ticketing system for a Rails application. I now need to send an e-mail when a new ticket is created. I thus created the following Mailer classes:

*app/mailers/application_mailer.rb*

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: Proc.new { "admin@domain" },
  from: 'admin@domain'

  def initialize(arg0, arg1)
    @base_url = 'http://app.domain'
  end

end
```

*app/mailers/ticket_mailer.rb*

```
class TicketMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def new_ticket(ticket)
    @ticket = ticket
    @url  = @base_url + '/tickets/' + @ticket.id.to_s
    mail(subject: "New Ticket: #{@ticket.title}")
  end
end
```

And modified the *Ticket* model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ticket_status
  belongs_to :ticket_type

  has_many   :ticket_follow_ups

  after_create :send_ticket_mail

  def send_ticket_mail()
    TicketMailer.new_ticket(self).deliver
  end
end
```

When I try to create a new ticket I am getting back the following exception:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `deliver' for nil:NilClass):
>
>   app/models/ticket.rb:20:in`send_ticket_mail'
>   app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:21:in `create'

I have tried to invoke the method directly from the controller, but the result is the same. What am I missing?

Comment: `TicketMailer.new.new_ticket(self).deliver` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this problem is caused by the `initialized` method in the `ApplicationMailer` class. Things function as expected if it is removed and the url is stored with a constant:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: Proc.new { "admin@domain" },
  from: 'admin@domain'

  BASE_URL = 'http://app.domain'
end
```

Naturally, the `TicketMailer` class has to be modified to use the constant.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this  as

```
  def send_ticket_mail()
    TicketMailer.new.new_ticket(self).deliver
   end
```

Comment: I get a different error: "NoMethodError (private method `new' called for TicketMailer:Class):
  app/models/ticket.rb:21:in `send_ticket_mail'
  app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:21:in `create'"